# Can non-food be treyf?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

If I placed my kosher food on a non-kashered surface that I knew had never been used for food, is my food still kosher?

I would be interested in whether there could be concerns of bugs--but that is not my main question. My main question is whether particles or transfer of non-food can ever make something treyf.

If not, what is the property of food makes it able to treyf something up? (Or, put another way, "What makes something 'food'?") Is it the property of taste? Good/appealing taste? "Taste or nutrition"? Something else?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17386/transfer-of-taste-to-from-non-food-items

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62318/how-many-degrees-of-separation-from-food-does-one-have-to-kasher

Comment: These two mitzvot on this (http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm) list of 613 seem possibly relevant, especially the second (the first merely supplies eight examples of ~"treyf" non-foods): --That eight species of creeping things defile by contact (Lev. 11:29-30) 
--That foods become defiled by contact with unclean things (Lev. 11:34)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17386?

Comment: @msh210 I think that question is asking if an item like a heating pad can be used to transfer food taste into, say, a kosher appliance. It seems much closer to my question about degrees of separation (2nd "related" link) than this. I am trying to ask if the non-food item itself has any "taste" of its own, basically.